# Azure Logic App gives 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have created simple Azure Function and I'm trying to call it in a Logic App.
But Logic App gives error 503 Service Unavaible.

[503 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U00Qn.png)

Logic app design:

[logic app design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7WcM.png)

I'm totally new to this, what can be the issue?

Comment: is your function protected (function level) or anonymous? what type of trigger (http, queue, blob storage)? can you run the function alone ?

Comment: @AnassKartit `public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)`

Comment: please test the function without logic app by running a test from the portal first

Comment: @AnassKartit How to check if it's running without error or not in azure portal?

Comment: try to hit your function using postman, does it work? i doubt it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the status of Azure function if it is running from the portal
[image: Function status]

then click the specific function to get the URL that should be called from Logic App
[image]

Comment: Yes it is running & available

Comment: and I'm calling function into logic app directly through Azure Functions step. I updated the question with logic app design, check.